# Compressing HTML inside PHP

Tags: php, html

I use yuicompressor for minimizing CSS and UglifyJS for minimizing JS files.

I am trying to minimize the non-php part (html portion) within a PHP files.

Note that I am not trying to use any php function which outputs minimized html. Instead, my idea is to use a tool like yuicompressor or UglifyJS  which only minimizes the html portion inside a php file (and not compress the php part) so that I can upload this minimized file and there is no minimizing needed at run time.

Please let me know if this is a good approach or not and any such tool exists.

I found some similar questions in this site, but all of them are focusing on run-time minimizing using php libraries.

Comment: Why would you want to make your `php` code less readable ? If you want to save traffic, use `ob_start` and process the html before sending

Comment: I was trying to use two files. One is my original source code and once my coding is completed, I will minimize and upload the minimized version to server.  So, my code will be readable while the production server will have minimized version and there is no additional processing needed using ob_start (i use same approach with css and js files)

Comment: You mean you're looking for a library that does stuff like `$c12='class="One Two"'` .. `echo "<div $c12>";` automatically? I'm not sure questions like that are on topic.